# Is there a way to make checkboxes created dynamically stick to another element upon resizing the window?

Tags: html, css

I'm putting together a simple todo application where the individual checkboxes and the labels belonging to them are created dynamically as the user presses the 'Add' button. I would like the checkboxes that are created to be aligned to the left at the time of creation, relative to the left side of the input text field. I could actually solve this part using the margin-left property.

What I would like is that the checkboxes stay where they are upon resizing the browser window either from the left or the right side and they keep sticking to the leftmost part of the input text field.

[The black vertical line in the image is a guide I drew to indicate where I would like my checkboxes to stick upon resizing the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAV6u.png)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My JavaScript Todo App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/myStyle.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="outerContainer">
   <div id="top" class="topContainer">
       <label for="todoInput">
           <input id="todoInput" type="text">
       </label>
       <button id="addButton">Add</button>
   </div>

   <div id="middle" class="middleContainer">
       <ul id="todoList" class="middleTodoList"></ul>
   </div>
</div>

</body>
<script src="js/todo.js"></script>
</html>
```

myStyle.css

```
li {
    list-style: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

.outerContainer {
}

.topContainer {
    text-align: center;
}

.middleContainer {
}

.middleTodoList {
    text-align: center;
}
```

todo.js

```
const todoInput = document.getElementById('todoInput');
const addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
const todoList = document.getElementById('todoList');

let listElementId = 0;

addButton.addEventListener('click', event => {

const checkBox = document.createElement('input');
checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
checkBox.setAttribute("id", todoInput.value);

const itemLabel = document.createElement('label');
itemLabel.setAttribute('for', todoInput.value);

const bottomDivision = document.getElementById('middle');
const listElement = document.createElement('li');
const todoInputValue = todoInput.value;

    if (todoInputValue) {
        listElement.id = 'list-item-' + listElementId++;

        itemLabel.append(todoInputValue);
        listElement.append(checkBox, itemLabel);
        todoList.append(listElement);
        document.body.appendChild(bottomDivision);
    }

    todoInput.value = '';
});
```

Comment: You are moving the entire list to the body, outside of the outerContainer, with the last line the IF statement "document.body.appendChild(bottomDivision);". I guess this is not intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a solution that I like and does what I needed. I modified the HTML in a way that the two pair of `<div>` tags that were previously encapsulated in an outer `<div>` tag now exist on their own.

index.html

```
<div id="top" class="topContainer">
    <label for="todoInput">
        <input id="todoInput" type="text">
    </label>
    <button id="addButton">Add</button>
</div>

<div id="middle" class="middleContainer">
    <ul id="todoList" class="middleTodoList"></ul>
</div>
```

I also added the following attributes to these class selectors.

myStyle.css

```
.topContainer {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 5vh;
    display: flex;
}

.middleContainer {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.middleTodoList {
    min-width: 11rem;
}
```